# N tuples of natural numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, elementary-set-theory

I have a question about elements of $N^k$,k a positive integer.

> For all $1 < i < j$, no $i$ tuple is a $j$ tuple BUT 1-tuple may be $i$ tuple
>   for some $i>1$.

Why? Are there any nontrivial examples of this observation?

How do I understand this statement inductively via the pairing operation?

FOR SOURCE SEE [THIS](http://u.osu.edu/friedman.8/files/2014/01/1.1GenForm020611-yd24yb.pdf) , page 4.

Comment: What is a "i-tuple"?

Comment: This is the part of the question to properly understand what it is and how is it best to define it to get the displayed statement true. $i$ is a positive ineteger.

Comment: If $i < j$, clearly no $i$-uple can be a $j$-uple, because the first has $i$ elements (numbers) while the second has $j \ne i$.

Comment: It seems like the $i$- tuple is not something natural like $(n_1,\dots,n_i)$

Comment: See [THIS](http://u.osu.edu/friedman.8/files/2014/01/1.1GenForm020611-yd24yb.pdf) page 4.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA however they claim this is NOT so for $i=1$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I wouldn't dare asking a question which confuses this. However see the page 4 in the reference.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I'm not sure. However the source is detailed enough.

Comment: OK, but where is (page 4) the assertion : "$1$-tuple may be $i$ tuple for some $i>1$" ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55705/discussion-between-user122424-and-mauro-allegranza).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA -3rd paragraph, "We rely on the fact". I think that the ineqalities $1<i<j$ are of importance.

Comment: It seems to me that there is nothing "deep" in the def. He consider multivariate functions $(f,k), k \ge 2$ i.e. functions whose values are not a (single) nu,ber but a tuple (an array of number) with *arity* $k$. The case $k=1$ is excluded simply becuase for $k=1$ we have the "standard" functions.

Comment: Thus, I think, what the author needs is : $i, j \ge 2$ (i.e. $i,j > 1$) and $i < j$.

Comment: I think the answer is in the first paragraph on page 5.  If $k=1$ there is an ambiguity, so 1-tuples are left out of the definition on page 4 (where $i$ is strictly greater than 1.)

Comment: Why there is an ambiguity when $k=1$? This is what I was originally asking for. Can you be more specific about this case?